# Error: No component factory found for MatSnackBarContainer

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've started a simple angular material project and trying to display the Snack-bar on page load. But it is throwing following error:-

> ERROR Error: No component factory found for MatSnackBarContainer. Did you add 
>       it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

I've even included AppComponent in entry component list in `app.module.ts` but it is not working.

Here's my app.component.html:-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [MatSnackBar]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'snackbarapp';

  constructor(public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    this.snackBar.open('hello', 'world', { duration: 2000 });
  }
}
```

Here is app.module.ts:-

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { Overlay } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule ],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  providers: [MatSnackBar, Overlay],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I've following dependencies:-

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You must have to add [`MatSnackBarModule`](https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api) in app.module.ts in prior to use SnackBar Module:

```
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material';
```

- Add `MatSnackBarModule` in imports array
- You have to add the related component *(in which you are using the snackbar component)* in `declarations` and `bootstrap` array:

```
 @NgModule({
   declarations: [
    AppComponent  <-- here
  ],

 imports: [
   MatSnackBarModule  <-- here
 ],

  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent  <-- here
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the [`Working StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4onxw)